# How can I rip my DVD to play them on my TV?

Tags: macos, software-recommendation

I would like to rip a DVD on to Mac then onto a multimedia device to play them on my TV set.

Is there a software that will help me to do so?

Answer (score 14):

You can use [**HandBrake**](http://handbrake.fr).

> HandBrake is an open-source, GPL-licensed, multiplatform, multithreaded video transcoder, available for MacOS X, Linux and Windows.

There are a lot of built-in preset  you can chose from to rip your DVD to a format you'll be able to play on your multimedia device.

Comment: In addition to Handbrake, you may require additional software such as Fairmount if the disc you want to rip has copy protection, but all the details will be available via the Handbrake pages.

Comment: IIRC you should only need [VLC](http://www.videolan.org/) to be installed in your /Applications/ folder, but there's no reason not to have [Fairmount](http://www.metakine.com/products/fairmount/) around too.

Answer (score 5):

I absolutely agree that Handbrake is a great tool to use.

However, I got [Ripit](http://thelittleappfactory.com/ripit/) in one of the Mac software bundles, and it's a great program too, especially if you want something that will:

- automatically start running as soon as you insert a DVD (and eject when it's done, if you want)
- not only rip the DVD but also pull out individual episodes from a DVD of a TV show, etc.

Generally I use RipIt to make VIDEO_TS folders out of DVDs and then use Handbrake to convert the Video_TS files into video files. The nice thing about that setup is that I can rip a bunch of DVDs, and then set the Handbrake queue to process the VIDEO_TS files, and just leave the computer to run unattended until it has finished.

RipIt is $25, which will be a deal-breaker for some, especially when HandBrake is free, but if you've purchased Mac bundles in the past, you might already have a license code for it.

Comment: It's also worthwhile to point out that running Handbrake directly on the DVD may wear out your drive over time (due to the sometimes non-linear access).

Comment: (old I know) I use Disk Utility to create a disk image, then run Handbrake on that. You may need to let DVD Player try to play your DVD first - there's some weird interaction between CSS copy protection that makes Disk Utility give permission errors some times, but seems to work fine if you "bless" the DVD by playing it.

Answer (score 0):

I use [ripIt](http://thelittleappfactory.com/ripit/) mainly because it's so easy to use (I also tried handbrake). it cost 25$ but you can rip 10 DVDs for free to try it...

Answer (score 0):

Just use itunes movies and burn to disk... DVD-R's are pretty cheap, then just convert it on videora (free) or if you have a ps3, just stick it on a USB stick

Answer (score -1):

My vote goes to Handbrake for ripping, but you could also use Disk Utility to simply make an ISO of the DVD.